# Prove X is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Prove $X = (X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a martingale w/rt $\mathscr{F}$ where X is given by:

$X_0 = 1$

and for $n \geq 1$

$X_{n+1} = 2X_n$ w/ prob 1/2

$X_{n+1} = 0$ w/ prob 1/2

and $\mathscr{F_n} = \mathscr{F_n}^{X} \doteq \sigma(X_0, X_1, ..., X_n)$.

I think that $X_{n} = 2^{n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} 1_{A_i} \forall n \geq 0$ where $A_1 = \{ \omega \in \Omega | X_{2}(\omega) = 2 X_1(\omega) \} \in \mathscr{F}$ as follows:

$X_{1} = 2X_0* 1_{A_1} + 0*1_{A_1^c}$

$X_{2} = 2X_1* 1_{A_2} + 0*1_{A_2^c}$

$=2(2X_0* 1_{A_1} + 0*1_{A_1^c})*1_{A_2} + 0*1_{A_2^c}$

Is that right? If not, why? If so, here is my attempt:

(leaving out adaptability and integrability stuff)

We must show that $E[X_{n+1}|\mathscr{F_n}] \equiv E[2^{n+1} \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} 1_{A_i}|\mathscr{F_n}] = 2^n \prod_{i=1}^{n} 1_{A_i}$? Is that right?

help please?

Comment: what is $X$? you only have the indexed version of it, $X_i$.

Comment: @Calculon Edited in first line. Thanks. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \{\mathscr{F_n}\}, \mathbb{P})$ where $\mathscr{F_n} = \mathscr{F_n}^{X} \doteq \sigma(X_0, X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, show that  $X = (X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a $(\mathscr{F}_n^X, \mathbb{P})$-martingale where $X$ is given by:

$X_{n+1} = 2X_n$ w/ prob 1/2

$X_{n+1} = 0$ w/ prob 1/2

and $X_0 = 1$.

Define the iid random variables $V_0 = 1$,

$V_1, V_2, \ldots \sim P(V_i = 0) = P(V_i = 2) = 1/2$. Then, $X_n = \prod_{i=0}^{n} V_i$.

1. $X_n$'s are bounded and hence integrable.
2. $X_n$'s are adapted to their natural filtration.
3. $E[X_n \mid \mathscr{F_m}] = X_m$

\begin{align}
\text{LHS} & = E\left[\prod_{i=0}^{n} V_i \mid \mathscr{F_m}\right] \\
& = E\left[\prod_{i=0}^{n} V_i \mid \mathscr{F_m}\right] \\
& = E\left[\prod_{i=0}^{m} V_i \prod_{i=m+1}^{n} V_i\mid \mathscr{F_m}\right] \\
& = E\left[X_m \prod_{i=m+1}^{n} V_i\mid \mathscr{F_m}\right] \\
& = X_m E\left[\prod_{i=m+1}^{n} V_i\mid  \mathscr{F_m}\right] \\
& = X_m E\left[\prod_{i=m+1}^{n} V_i\right] \tag{*} \\
& = X_m \prod_{i=m+1}^{n} E\left[V_i\right] \text{ by the independence of the $V_i$'s} \\
& = X_m \prod_{i=m+1}^{n} E\left[V_i\right] \\
& = X_m \prod_{i=m+1}^{n} (1) \\
& = \text{RHS} \quad \text{QED}
\end{align}

(*)

$\mathscr G_m = \sigma(V_1,\ldots,V_m) \supset \mathscr F_m$

Being independent of $\mathscr G_m$ implies being independent of $\mathscr F_m$

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things to check:

1. $X_n$ is measurable with respect to $F_n$: This is ok by definition of $F$.
2. $X_n$ is integrable: as $X_n$ is bounded, so that is ok.
3. (the big part) $E[X_{n+1}|X_n] = X_n$:

conditionally to $X_n$, there are two options:

- with probability 1/2, $X_{n+1} = 2X_n$
- with probability 1/2, $X_{n+1} = 0$

hence $$E[X_{n+1}|X_n] = 1/2\times  2X_n + 1/2\times 0 = X_n
$$

Comment: Thanks. Aren't we supposed to show $$E[X_{n+1}|\mathscr{F_n}] = X_n
$$ ?

Comment: yes. In the case of F being the natural filtration of the process, this is the same, but you are right.

Comment: mookid, sorry I really don't get that last line at all. Isn't it that $E[X_{n+1}|\mathscr{F_n}]$ is $2X_n$ xor $0$? If 0, then no prob, and if $2X_n$, then...? What makes you say that your conditional expectation is prob times value + prob times value? That looks more like $E[X_{n+1}]$ rather than $E[X_{n+1}|\mathscr{F_n}]$...?

Comment: 1. E[...|X_n] is a random variable, and more precisely a deterministic function of the *random* variable X_n. And E[...] is a deterministic value. This is for the last question.

Comment: 2. then, with probability 1/2 this is the $random variable$ $X_{n+1}$ which is equal to $X_n$. Not its expected value.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH THANKS!!!! HAHAHAHAHAHAHA

Comment: mookid, in retrospect, I'm not quite sure I get it. Iydmma, may you please explain rigorously?  I suspect indicator functions may be involved

Comment: @mookid Condition 3. is faulty and should read $E(X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n)=X_n$ almost surely, as written in every definition of martingale. Exercise: Find a process $(X_n)$ such that $E(X_{n+1}\mid X_n)=X_n$ almost surely but $(X_n)$ is **not** a martingale.

Comment: @Did Thanks for clarifying that. I'm guessing this one is wrong then...? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282010/gambling-game-martingale#comment2603506_1282170