# Is a probability of 0 or 1 given information up to time t unchanged by information thereafter?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \{\mathscr{F}_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, \mathbb{P})$, let $A \in \mathscr{F}$.

Suppose $$\exists t \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{s.t.} \ E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] = 1$$ Does it follow that $$E[1_A | \mathscr{F_{s}}] = E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] \ \forall s > t \ ?$$ What about $\forall s < t$?

What if instead $$\exists t \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{s.t.} \ E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] = 0 \ ?$$ Or what if $$E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] = p \ \text{for some} \ p \in (0,1) \ ?$$

---

What I tried:

---

Case 1: $E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] = 1$

$$E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] = 1$$

$$\to E[E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}]] = E[1]$$

$$\to E[1_A] = 1$$

and [maybe for this reason](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494682/is-it-correct-to-say-that-pa-1-to-pab-1-pa-1-to-pab-pa) $$E[1_A | \mathscr{F_{s}}] = E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] \ \text{QED for case 1?}$$

If so, I suspect for similar reasons, we can deduce:

---

Case 2: $E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] = 0$

$$E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] = 0$$

$$\to E[1_A | \mathscr{F_{s}}] = E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] \ \text{QED for case 2?}$$

Comment: Why is $E[1_A|\mathscr{F}_t] = 1$?

Comment: @Olorun ? $E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}]$ by assumption.

Comment: Where did you state that assumption?

Comment: @Olorun Lol sorry. That's in cases. Will edit. Thanks

Comment: Actually  $E[1_A | \mathscr{F_t}] $ is a random variable. And by assumption $\{0,1\}$ its values.

Comment: @NikitaEvseev Sorry for the confusion. I did not mean that it is a random variable that takes on 0 or 1 for values. I really meant for it to be equal to 0 or equal to 1. Will edit. thanks

Comment: @NikitaEvseev Post as answer? Thanks!

Comment: @NikitaEvseev are you sure your tower property is right? [1](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/6/4/a/64a588912255dd25be38be6aa3b502fb.png) [2](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/5/0/5/505be81ce7b7d0bfd58ee1ab05f3ea43.png)

Comment: @BCLC I missed the tower property (the wrong comment is removed).

Comment: @NikitaEvseev still helpful as it turns out ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_t]=1$, then $\Bbb E[1_A]=1$ (almost surely), which is the same as $1_A=1$.  In this case $\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_s]=1$ (almost surely) for each $s$.

Likewise, if $\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_t]=0$, then $\Bbb E[1_A]=0$, which is the same as $1_A=0$ (almost surely).  In this case $\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_s]=0$ (almost surely) for each $s$.

If $\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_t]=p$, for a constant $p\in(0,1)$, then $\Bbb E[1_A]=p$, and  (for a fixed bounded $\mathscr F_t$-measurable random variable $F$)

$$\Bbb E[1_A\cdot F]=\Bbb E[E[1_A\cdot F|\mathscr F_t]]=\Bbb E[F\cdot E[1_A|\mathscr F_t]]$$

$$=\Bbb E[p\cdot F]=p\Bbb E[F]=\Bbb E[1_A]\cdot\Bbb E[F]$$

meaning that $1_A$ and $F$ are independent. In other words, $\sigma(A)$ and $\mathscr F_t$ are independent. So $\sigma(A)$ and $\mathscr F_s$ are also independent if $s<t$ and hence $E[1_A|\mathscr F_s] = E[1_A] = p$ . This may fail if $s>t$.

---

OP edit: Is independence needed to say $\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_s]=p$ if s < t?

If $\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_t]=p$, for a constant $p\in(0,1)$, then we have

$\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_s]=E[E[1_A|\mathscr F_t]|\mathscr F_s] = E[p|\mathscr F_s] = p$

I guess the idea is that [a constant is both independent of $\mathscr F_s$ and $\mathscr F_s$-measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303735/questions-on-kolmogorov-zero-one-law-proof-in-williams).

Comment: Same for p?....

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Wait. How do you know that 'In this case $\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_s]=1$ (almost surely) for each $s$.' and 'In this case $\Bbb E[1_A|\mathscr F_s]=0$ (almost surely) for each $s$.'? Is that because $1_A = 1$ and $1_A = 0$, respectively? Edited such. Feel free of course to rollback

Comment: Um John Dawkins how does zero covariance imply independence in this case? I think instead of $F$, you should use $1_{F_t}$ where $F_t \in \mathscr{F_t}$ ? It seems that that would indeed show that $\sigma(A)$ and $\mathscr F_t$ are independent

Comment: $1_{F_t}$ is a special kind of "bounded $\mathscr F_t$-measurable random variable" (for $F_t\in\mathscr F_t$).

Comment: If you don't use that how do the last equations prove Independence?

Comment: I am using the fact that two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr B$  are independent if and only if $\Bbb E[AB]=\Bbb E[A]\Bbb E[B]$ for all bounded $\mathscr A$-measurable real-valued functions $A$ and all bounded $\mathscr B$-measurable real-valued functions  $B$

Comment: wow. That's really interesting. If I use indicator 1_F_t though, the proof still holds?

Comment: Yes, the argument still works.

Comment: John Dawkins, is independence needed? Edited