# $\max (X_t, a)$ is not a martingale, counterexample

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, conditional-expectation

It is quite easy to prove that if $[X_t \}_{t \in [0,T]}$ is a martingale, then for any number $a \in \mathbb{R}$ $ \{\max (X_t,a)\} _t$ is a submartingale and  $ \{\min (X_t, a)\} _t$ but I cannot come up with a counterexample which proves that those need not be martingales.

That is, I want to find a martingale $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}$ and a constant $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\mathbb{E}\left(\max (X_t,a) | F_s \right) < \max(X_s, a)$$ for all $s \le t$ and adequately for minimum: $$\mathbb{E}\left(\min (X_t,a) | F_s \right) > \min(X_s, a)$$ for all $s \le t$

Could you tell me how/where to look for such examples?

Comment: "I cannot come up with a counterexample which proves that those need not be martingales." This is rather surprising since *every* martingale works (except when $X_t\geqslant a$ almost surely or $X_t\leqslant a$ almost surely, naturally).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** An easier way to show that $(Z_t)$ is not a martingale  is to find some $t$ with $\mathbb{E}(Z_0)\neq \mathbb{E}(Z_t)$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how I can modify a martingale, that is what constant $a$ to choose so that the expectations may differ for a certain $t$?

Comment: Can we for example take the absolute value of a random variable? For $X_1, X_2, ...$ iid with $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1) = 1/2$ $\{ S_n \}$ is a martingale. And here we have $\mathbb{E}(S_n) = 0$ and also  $\mathbb{E}(|S_n|) = 0$ but I think it's not a martingale...

Comment: No, that was very stupid. We have $\mathbb{E}(S_1) =\mathbb{E}(X_1) = 0$ but $\mathbb{E}(|S_1|) =\mathbb{E}(|X_1|) = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}(|S_2|) =\mathbb{E}(|X_1 + X_2|) =2$ because $|X_1 + X_2| \in \{0,2\}$ with probabilities $1/2, 1/2$

Comment: And when it comes to minimum we could take the negative part $\min(S_n, 0)$ and get similar results to those above. Is that right?

Answer (score -2):

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \{\mathscr F_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}, \mathbb P)$ be a filtered probability space where $T > 0$.

> [If we have two $(\{\mathscr F_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}, \mathbb P)-$martingales $X$ and $Y$, it does not follow that $\max(X,Y)$ is a $(\{\mathscr F_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}, \mathbb P)-$martingale.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564178/maximum-of-martingales) $\tag{*}$

Now, $\forall a \in \mathbb R$ the stochastic process $A = (A_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ given by $a = A_t \ \forall t \in [0,T]$ is a $(\{\mathscr F_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}, \mathbb P)-$martingale.

Following the proof of $(*)$, we can show that it does not follow that $\max(X,A) = (\max(X_t,a))_{t \in [0,T]}$ is a $(\{\mathscr F_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}, \mathbb P)-$martingale.

---

Pf based on [answers here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564178/maximum-of-martingales):

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ be our probability space.

Let $X_0, X_1, X_2, ...$ be iid random variables s.t.

$$P(X_i = 1) = 1/2 = P(X_i = -1)$$

Define $W^X_n := \sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i$.

Consider the filtration $\mathscr F_{n} := \mathscr F_{n}^X$ for $n = 0,1,...$

Note that $W^X_n$ is a martingale w/rt $\mathscr F_{n}$.

Let $a \in \mathbb R$. Consider $M = (M_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ where

$$M_n := \max(W_n^X, a) = W_n^X 1_{A_n} + a 1_{A_n^C}$$

where $A_n = \{W_n^X \ge a\}$ and $0 < P(A_n) < 1 (**)$

Let us try to show (and hopefully fail in trying) that $E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = M_{n-1}$:

$$E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = E[W_n^X 1_{A_n} + a 1_{A_n^C}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] $$

$$= E[W_n^X 1_{A_n}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] + E[a 1_{A_n^C}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] $$

$$= E[W_n^X 1_{A_n}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] + a E[1_{A_n^C}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] $$

Now consider this. If at time 1, we have that $W_1^X = a + 0.5$ it's possible that at time 2, we have $W_2^X = a - 0.5$. Thus, $M_2 = a$ but $M_1 = W_1^X$

Formally:

If at time n, we have $\omega \in A_n$ (ie $W_n^X(\omega) \ge a$), then

$$E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = E[W_n^X 1_{A_n}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] + 0$$

$$= E[W_n^X|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = W_{n-1}^X$$

But is it that $W_{n-1}^X = M_{n-1}$?

Not necessarily. It could be that $\omega \in A_{n-1}^C$ (ie $W_{n-1}^X(\omega) \le a$). Hence, $M_{n-1} = a$

$\therefore,$ it is not necessarily true that $E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = M_{n-1}$. QED

I hope you don't mind that I used $\mathbb N$ instead of $[0,T]$ :P

---

$(**)$

Oh also $P(A_n) \notin \{0,1\}$ is important:

If $P(A_j) = 0$ or $1 \ \forall j \in \mathbb N$, then $M_n$ is $W_n^X$ or a a.s. Hence, $M$ is a $(\{\mathscr F_n\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}, \mathbb P)-$martingale (at least almost surely) because such implies $1_{A_1} = 1_{A_2} = ...$ a.s., in particular, $1_{A_n} = 1_{A_{n-1}}$ a.s..

This might be relevant: [Is a probability of 0 or 1 given information up to time t unchanged by information thereafter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515756/)

Comment: Where are we supposed to find an example, or a proof, that $(\max(X_t,a))_t$ is not a martingale in all this?

Comment: @Did The first part? It follows from $(*)$. Did you downvote? Is $(*)$ false? Is my proof wrong?

Comment: The first part does not provide any example of a martingale $(X_t)$ and a real number $a$ such that $(Y^a_t)$ is not a martingale, with $Y^a_t=\max(X_t,a)$, nor any way to show that such would exist. You know, what the OP is asking about...

Comment: @Did I edited. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Still not answering the question in the least.

Comment: @Did Ah wait. Now I think I understand you. A maximum of two martingales is not necessarily a martingale but it could be. I merely provided a counterexample proving $(*)$ but not really answering OP. Okay going to edit. thanks ^-^

Comment: @Did Done. Thanks again.

Comment: Still no proof. (I am tired of mentioning the fact so, if no further comment is added, please consider the present one still holds.)